# canvas offset for jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

i have set up a pen here

http://codepen.io/prantikv/pen/LEbRKY

i am using a canvas to stroke the mouse or touch. It works fine when jquery or jquery mobile is not attached but as soon as i attach it i am getting an offset in the canvas and the drawing only on the Y-axis.

i am using the following code to draw:

```
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var isDrawing;

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  console.log(e);
  console.log(e.pageX,e.pageY);
};
el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.layerX, e.layerY);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
};
```

what seems to be the problem. i tried using layerY and pageY and screenY but non are accurate.

which values should i take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var jqEl = jQuery('#c')
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var isDrawing;
el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX - jqEl.position().left, e.clientY - jqEl.position().top);
};
el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - jqEl.position().left, e.clientY - jqEl.position().top);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
};
```